# NoSuchPortException

Tags: java

I installed `javax.comm` API. Whenever I try to execute the code below

```
CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM49");
```

I'm getting `NoSuchPortException`.

I tried listing the ports but it shows none of the ports.

I also searched in net regarding this and tried placing the Files of api in all the folders as i read, but still now im getting the exception.Help me solve this issue and it would be helpfull if you specify the proper installation of the api.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to list ports

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier port = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
            String type;
            switch (port.getPortType()) {
                case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                    type = "Parallel";
                    break;
                case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                    type = "Serial";
                    break;
                default: /// Shouldn't happen
                    type = "Unknown";
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println(port.getName() + ": " + type);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Program gives no output...its only blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/CommPortIdentifier.html#getPortIdentifiers%28%29) method to get a list of all port identifiers which are available on the local system.

Comment: it returns null when i call nextElement() of the returned object

Comment: This seems to mean that the system has no ports which are supported. The CommPortIdentifier has a static method addPortName which requires a CommDriver object, which implements a custom device driver. I guess you would have to implement it yourself.